# How to troubleshoot failed Windows updates "We couldn't complete the updates...."?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I am using Windows 8.1 and I have about 30 important Windows updates. It seems I can't have any of them get updated without failing and getting a "We couldn't complete the updates.. Undoing changes". Even when I choose to update just a single update, Windows tries to update a whole bunch of them. I am sure if this because of dependencies or what.  Also when I try to hide all of them, at some point they come back and Windows shows them again and the cycle repeats.

I also used a tool from Microsoft which supposedly fixes Windows update issues. It reports it fixed errors but every time I run it, it says it fixed errors. If it fixed the errors then why is it still saying it fixed errors after each run. It doesn't matter how many times I run it or if reboot. I feel it's not a reliable tool.

What's the process to troubleshoot the failed updates? I feel the updates are just piling up over time and I am stuck. I want either the updates to be hidden for good (unless I specifically show them again) or get installed correctly.

Comment: Anything in the Event Logs regarding the failed updates (like an actual error code)?  Try the basics: Stop the Windows Udpate and Background Intelligent Transfer (BITS) services. Go delete the `c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder, Start the Windows Update service again, and try updating.  Any difference?

Comment: Windows 8 requires a number of folders and files exist in their standard locations for update to succeed. After I had deleted some folders, updates failed. See https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/case-of-the-kb2919355-installation-failure-windows-8-1-update-1/ for more information. Hope this helps...

Comment: share the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS. I'll take a look at it

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It didn't help

Comment: Anything in the Event Logs regarding the failed updates (like an actual error code)?

Comment: I went through the steps in this post using dism and sfc and it didn't help. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/error-0x800f0922-when-installing-kb-2919355/ca99de84-a8ab-4d78-a7b2-e5dc562a418f?page=7

Comment: Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 All updates failed with error 0x800F0922

Comment: @magicandre1981 The cbs.log is at filedropper.com/cbs

Comment: Maybe it's related to free space in System reserved disk partition? I have one free at 70MB and another at 44MB. I have to do some research on how to expand them.

Comment: You get the error **0X8004402f** which means **"Error creating temporary file"**. I found this link (http://blogs.technet.com/b/smsandmom/archive/2008/08/27/configmgr-2007-client-installation-fails-with-unable-to-compile-the-file-ccmclasses-mof.aspx) which says this can happen when TEMP folder is not configured correctly.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes my temp folder is in a ram disk. Never had a problem with it before. When I switched to one on a regular drive, the updates installed fine. Went back to the ram disk.  Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error `0X8004402f` which means `"Error creating temporary file"`. I found this [Blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/smsandmom/archive/2008/08/27/configmgr-2007-client-installation-fails-with-unable-to-compile-the-file-ccmclasses-mof.aspx) which says this can happen when TEMP folder is not configured correctly. So set the TEMP folder back to a local folder on C: instead of using a RAM disk.